# Duplicate events on Thunderbird Lightning

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, google-calendar, lightning

It seems that Google have stepped up security and provider for Google Calendar requires  a popup authentication like "Online Accounts".

As soon as I did authorise the calendar, I ended up with duplicate entries for each and every event in my calendar. They are not present in the Online version of the events.

How do I delete the cached copies on my PC without erasing the account settings?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Please look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/provider-for-google-calendar/t0HWHX35LE0 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1079659.

The author of the GData plugin is actively working to correct the problem, and given the track record of the plugin, I am sure he will.

I can confirm  that removing the calendar from Thunderbird and adding it again seems to fix the problem (I am using the beta 1.0.1 from the aforementioned bug report).